# Static membership in Apache Kafka for consumers

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I got to know in a recent version of kafka, static membership strategy is available for consumer subscription instead of early dynamic membership detection which helps is scenario when consumer is bounces as part of rolling deployment. Now when consumer is up after getting bounced it catches up with the same partition and starts processing.

My question is what will happen if we have deliberately shutdown consumer ? How message in partition to which particular consumer was subscribed will get processed ?

Answer (score 1):

After a consumer has been shutdown, the Consumer Group will undergo a normal rebalance after the consumer's `session.timeout.ms` has elapsed.

https://kafka.apache.org/10/documentation/streams/developer-guide/config-streams.html#kafka-consumers-and-producer-configuration-parameters

When configuring Static Membership, it is important to increase the `session.timeout.ms` higher than the default of 10000 so that consumers are not prematurely rebalanced. Set this value high enough to allow workers time to start, restart, deploy, etc. Otherwise, the application may get into a restart cycle if it misses too many
heartbeats during normal operations. Setting it too high may cause
long periods of partial unavailability if a worker dies, and the
workload is not rebalanced. Each application will set this value
differently based on its own availability needs.

Comment: Please be certain to disclose your affiliation when linking to your own blog. I recommend reading [How not to be a spammer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) for guidance regarding self-promotion on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

If you manually subscribe then you would have to deal with that scenario in your application code - that's the advantage of automatic subscription, all partitions will be assigned to one of the group after a rebalance.

To cater for consumers permanently leaving the group with manual subscription, I guess you would need to track subscriptions somewhere and maybe have each consumer pinging to let you know it is alive.

I'm not sure what use cases the manual subscription is catering for - I will have to go back and check the Javadoc in KafkaConsumer, which is pretty comprehensive. As long as you have no local state in consumers the automatic subscription seems much safer and more resilient.